# Retrieve the filtertype of the ColumnFilter Plugin of jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datatable

I am using jQuery DataTable and found some nice Plugin for making filtering easier. It is called ColumnFilter and it is available here:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/

Using this plugin is really easy. Right after declaring the DataTable, it is configured like this:

```
oTable.columnFilter({
  aoColumns: [
    { type: "number-range" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" }
  ]
});
```

When actually filtering the datasource serverside, I need to know what types has been set in the columnfilter plugin. The reason behind this is, that I encapsulated a generic approach for filtering that basically allows me to do this on an entity in the serverside controller action:

```
Public Function DataProviderAction(ByVal dataTableParams As JQueryDataTableParamModel) As JsonResult
  Return GetJson(dataTableParams, Request.Params,
    Function(r) New String() {
      Convert.ToString(r.Id),
      r.Description,
      r.Comment})
End Function
```

This works due to the fact that the controller is derived from a generic basecontroller Of T. The GetJson method expects a Lambda expression for the creation of a string array. The rest (filtering, sorting and paging) is done in a couple of extension methods on IQueryable(Of T).

Somewhere down the road there exists a strategy that holds a couple of specific filter implementations that are independent of the actual type. This is realized with Dynamic Linq and looks like this:

```
Public Function ApplyFilter(Of T As {IDataObject})(entities As IQueryable(Of T), filterInfo As System.Tuple(Of String, String)) As IQueryable(Of T) Implements ISmartFilter.ApplyFilter
  Dim result As IQueryable(Of T) = Nothing

  Try
    result = entities.Where(If(filterInfo.Item1 = "", True, String.Format("{0}.ToLower().Contains(@0)", filterInfo.Item2)), filterInfo.Item1.ToLower)
  Catch
  End Try

  Return result
End Function
```

What happens here, is that this Where extension creates an expression that basically says something like "Where( Description.ToLower().Contains(filtertext))".

However, I need to call the correct strategy corresponding to the filtertype set in the UI. At the moment, I simply have a context class that holds instances of all Filters and implements a method that iterates through all of them, checking conditions on which it decides whether or not to apply this filter.

**It would be easier if I just KNEW the filtertype.** :)

So the question is:

How am I able to put the aoColumns array from dataTable.columnFilter into the parameter list of DataTable so that I can access it from the DataProviderAction method mentioned above?

I also must not alter any code of dataTable and/or columnFilter itself...

Answer (score 0):

Hm... I somehow found something like a solution.

What do you guys think about this:

In my jQuery initialization code of Datatables, I added an array with filtertype information like this:

```
 var filterList = [
                { type: "" },
                { type: "number-range" },
                { type: "text" },
                { type: "text" }
            ];
```

I then defined a helper function that creates a couple of aodata.push calls to inject those filtertypes into my json string:

```
fnServerObjectToArray = function () {
        return function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

            for (i = 0; i < filterList.length; i++) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "sFilter_" + i, "value": filterList[i].type });
            }

            $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                fnCallback(json);
            });
        }
    }
```

Within my datatables initialization I add this function as fnServerData:

```
var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
  ...          
  "sAjaxSource": "MyController/DataProviderAction",
            "fnServerData": fnServerObjectToArray(),
...
 });
```

And the columnFilter itself is now based on the array defined above:

```
 oTable.columnFilter({
            aoColumns: filterList
        });
```

Down the road up to the strategies, the context now holds the available filters within a dictionary:

```
Private Shared availableFilters As New Dictionary(Of String, ISmartFilter) From {
            {"number", New NumberFilter()},
            {"number-range", New NumberRangeFilter()},
            {"text", New TextFilter()}
        }
```

This way I can now apply the corresponding filter in such a way:

```
Public Shared Function ApplyFilter(Of T As {IDataObject})(entities As IQueryable(Of T), filterInfo As System.Tuple(Of String, String, String)) As IQueryable(Of T)

            Dim filteredEntities As IQueryable(Of T)

            Dim filter As ISmartFilter = Nothing

            If (availableFilters.TryGetValue(filterInfo.Item3.ToLower(), filter)) Then
                filteredEntities = availableFilters(filterInfo.Item3).ApplyFilter(entities, filterInfo)
            Else
                ' Default-Filter
                filteredEntities = availableFilters("text").ApplyFilter(entities, filterInfo)
            End If

            Return filteredEntities
        End Function
```